# Building Error: What's "-licucore" and how can I fix this error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, target

After a whole day I've fixed tens of error in a legacy project, but I'm blocked by this annoying problem. I've searched a lot on the web but cannot get a relevant answer to this.

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC -ObjC 
    error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -licucore
    error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -licucore is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Should I modify something in Build Settings or Build Phases, or somewhere in CocoaPods???

Add: Error happens on building a target and here are all the error info:

```
Libtool /Users/wangshudao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Diana-gfwxapulgdvudifuftotddpukijd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libDianaModels.a normal x86_64
cd /Volumes/HDD/Dev/workplace/iOS/Diana
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/wangshudao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Diana-gfwxapulgdvudifuftotddpukijd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/wangshudao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Diana-gfwxapulgdvudifuftotddpukijd/Build/Intermediates/Diana.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DianaModels.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DianaModels.LinkFileList -ObjC -lPods-Model-AFNetworking -lPods-Model-Mantle -lPods-Model-ReactiveCocoa -lPods-Model-SSKeychain -lPods-Model-TMCache -licucore -framework AVOSCloud -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework UIKit -ObjC -lPods-Model-AFNetworking -lPods-Model-Mantle -lPods-Model-ReactiveCocoa -lPods-Model-SSKeychain -lPods-Model-TMCache -licucore -framework AVOSCloud -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Foundation -lPods-Model -o /Users/wangshudao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Diana-gfwxapulgdvudifuftotddpukijd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libDianaModels.a
```

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC -ObjC 
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -licucore
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -licucore is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -licucore
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -licucore is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Comment: I've checked in the Other Linker Flags, there is a item is set as -l"icucore"

Comment: I fixed this by removing all the -l"icucore" in all the Pods.XXX.xcconfig files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing all the -l"icucore" in all the Pods.XXX.xcconfig files. They are auto-generated by the CocoaPods and I don't know how to control the these linker flags. Whatever, it works now...

Answer (score 0):

It's the command line option to the linker to tell it to link in `libicucore.a` (probably; but could also potentially be `libicucore.dylib`, but not likely under iOS).

You have to supply the library in order to fix the error.

Other potential reasons for the failure are:

- Not including the directory containing the library in any `-L` command line options.
- The "fat" library file not including the necessary CPU architecture, although the linker will produce a slightly different error message in that case.

See this [manpage](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/ld.1.html), although it's somewhat out-of-date (I cannot find Apple's current manpage for `ld`).

Comment: Do your suggestions can do some configurations in the iOS project? I'm sorry your answer is a little difficult to understand for me.

Comment: @vulgur My answer is vague, but that's because there isn't enough information to solve your particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-licucore` flag in `Other Linker Flags` in your project's target Build Settings. It may solve your problem.

Comment: And in the Other Linker Flags, it is set like -l"icucore"

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar error with `RegexKitLite`, and I fixed with this settings:

[image]

Comment: i got this by your suggestion: ```error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `f' in: -fobjc-arc```